# Video import to Movie Maker broken

Tags: windows, video, import, windows-movie-maker

I'm trying to import a 1 hour long video to Windows Movie Maker, but when I import it it's only 7 seconds long and has nothing on it. It has an error sign on it, and tells me to "double click to fix", which just removes it.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix it? The file runs fine when I watch it in Media Player.
Is it possible that the BBC (it's an iPlayer video) have put some sort of lock on it?

Comment: How did you download the video? If it was through downloading the WMV from BBC iPlayer, it has a form of DRM that prevents the videos being played about with. It's not possible to remove this DRM.

Comment: I'm fast asleep today, completely forgot about DRM, lol.
I downloaded the WMV version from the BBC website

Answer (score 2):

BBC iPlayer has a form of DRM on it that stops the WMV videos being imported into other programs - it's not a Movie Maker limitation, it's the DRM making things go a bit funky.